# Pagination appears on deleted questions and revision history, even if there's only one page

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, pagination

On all deleted questions where there's at least one answer, the *1* (indicating the first page) is shown where the pagination would be. But there's no need to, since there's only one page.

[image]

I guess this should be removed (it's also not clickable).

The same happens in revision histories:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Pagination links børken everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195306). Looks like someone done a pagination oopsie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination oopsie un-oopsied now.

The pager code has been recently changed (in part to support localization and in part to make it better) and this issue has escaped notice (as it appears to happen only in certain locations and not the main tested ones).