# Pagination links børken everywhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination

The pagination at the bottom of the users pages uses links that have all the parameter delimiters (`&`) escaped to `&amp;`.

The [overall users rank](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) page for example, links to `https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&amp;tab=reputation&amp;filter=all` instead of to `https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all`. Because of this the weekly rank, page two, is shown instead.

This is not limited to just the user pages; it appears that all pagination links are affected.

- The same problem can be seen with search result pagination, this [example search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+list+comprehension) renders the link to page 2 as `https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&amp;tab=relevance&amp;q=python%20list%20comprehension`. The second page returns no results because of this.
- The [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag page pagination links to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=2&amp;sort=newest&amp;pagesize=50`. Page two is returned but any sorting or page size parameters are lost. Because the site uses cookies for the `sort` and `pagesize` parameters this problem is less severe.
- For 10k+ users, you can filter the review queue history page to show only your own reviews; when you switch that on the pagination links there are broken as well: `https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/own/history?page=2&amp;userid=100297` for the close review history page, page two, filtered on my own reviews.

The footer software revision is rev 2013.8.30.981 and this problem appears to be browser independent.

Comment: Same problem occurring in search.

Comment: [børk, børk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY_Yf4zz-yo)

Comment: @animuson: it looks like most (all?) paginations are affected.

Comment: Really, downvotes on a confirmed, now fixed, bug? I'd love to hear the rationale for *that* voting behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix for this went out with the latest build.