# Broken links for changing page in SO -> Users

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design

The page links in squares at the bottom of [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) are broken, as in this example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&amp;tab=reputation&amp;filter=week
```

Note extra "amp;" after "&".

Actually, the links do work, but the GET attributes are lost. For instance, if you choose `filter=ALL` and then try to pass to page 2, you go back to default `filter=WEEK`.

Comment: The dreaded templating bug strikes again!

Comment: Related: [Pagination links børken everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195306/pagination-links-borken-everywhere)

Comment: @chuex How would I find this spelled with a funny empty set symbol? :-)

Comment: Not sure. I had read the linked question earlier and remembered it when you posted yours.

Comment: @chuex I was just kidding. But I can't vote as duplicated.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft - I cant either, but I just did FLAG it as a duplicate.